# Python datetime conversion to timestamps

Tags: python, datetime, time, timestamp

I am struggling to understand why the following lines of code

```
from datetime import datetime 

t1 = datetime(2019, 3, 31, 0, 0, 0).timestamp()
t2 = datetime(2019, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0).timestamp()
dt = t2-t1
print(f"dt = {dt} seconds.")
```

output

```
dt = 82800.0 seconds.
```

instead of

```
dt = 86400.0 seconds.
```

The time difference between t2 and t1 is clearly 1 day = 24 hours = 1440 minutes = 86400 seconds. Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you in a timezone where a DST change happens to happen on March 31st…?

Comment: It's exactly one hour. Maybe caused by time change: summer/winter time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling e.g. `datetime(2019, 3, 31, 0, 0, 0).timestamp()` will give you a timestamp that is localized to your machine's timezone since the datetime object is not aware of any timezone ("naive"; see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)). Apparently, you are in a timezone with a DST change on that date.

If you set the timezone to UTC for example (no DST), you will get the expected result:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
t1 = datetime(2019, 3, 31, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
t2 = datetime(2019, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
dt = t2-t1

print(f"dt = {dt} seconds.")
# dt = 86400.0 seconds.
```

Comment: @RiccardoAngeloGiro, glad I could help. It's better to stumble across such DST issues early on than bugfixing it later... I'd suggest to work with UTC whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

It was the day in your time zone when the clocks changed one hour forward because 82,000 is 23 x 60 x 60